# Guidance on a Complex Analysis question

Tags: complex-analysis

My homework question:  Show that all zeros of $$p(z)=z^4 + 6z + 3$$ lie in the circle of radius $2$ centered at the origin.

I know $p(z)$ has a zero-count of $4$ by using the  Fundamental Theorem of Algebra. Then using the Local Representation Theorem the $$\int \frac{n}{z+a} = 4(2 \pi i).$$ I am assuming $a=0$ since we are centered at the origin. I apologize for my lack of math-type.  What does $$= 8 \pi i$$ mean?  Am I going around the unit circle $4$ times?  Or is it even relevant to my final answer.  Which I am assuming is finding the coordinates to the $4$ singularities. I have always looked for my singularities in the values that make the denominator zero, but in this question my denominator is $z$.  $z=0$ doesn't seem right.  So the question is, am I suppose to factor the polynomial $z^4 + 6z + 3$ to find the zeros?

Thanks

Comment: @Crystal: I typeset the equations.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** This kind of questions are usually handled using [Rouche's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem). I suggest you look it up in the wikipedia article, where you can see an example of its usage. Also here's an [example](http://books.google.co.cr/books?id=wDsrQTPUaSsC&pg=PA77&dq=rouche%27s+theorem&hl=es&ei=YAvwTNmTOIX7lwej4JH9DA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=rouche%27s%20theorem&f=false).

The key is choosing wisely another function $f(z)$ with which to compare in the inequality in Rouche's theorem and such that you can easily decide how many zeroes does $f(z)$ have inside the region you are considering, which in your case is the circle $|z| < 2$.

About your other question, you don't need to factor the polynomial in order to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

Chhose $f(z)=z^4$ Then on $|z|=2$, $|f(z)-p(z)|<|p(z)|$ so by Rouche's Theorem $f(z)$ and $p(z)$ has same number of zeroes inside $|z|<2$ and we are done

Comment: You surely meant $|f(z)-p(z)|<|p(z)|$.

Comment: @girianshiido Thank you for notifying